# XPathExpressionException on xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I'm tring to get data from these xml :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.alternative.thy.com/" xmlns:req="http://www.thy.com/ws/requestHeader" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
      <ser:GS>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <requestHeader>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <req:clientCode>KL7MU</req:clientCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <req:clientUsername>BLABLA</req:clientUsername>
         </requestHeader>
      </ser:GS>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

To get clientUsername I write

```
        SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();

        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        message.writeTo(os);

        String xpath = "////requestHeader/req:clientUsername";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String sad = xPath.evaluate(xpath, new InputSource(
                new StringReader(os.toString())));
```

But it returns :javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException. I think my fail reson is xpath statement ////requestHeader/req:clientUsername is it correct statement?

Comment: Does the exception not have a message that tells you more or less exactly what's wrong? Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
soapenv//ser:GS//requestHeader//req:clientUsername
```

Comment: thank you. It does not give me an error but not returns any value. just returns empty string. I expected BLABLA as a result

Comment: try soapenv//ser:GS//requestHeader//req:clientUsername/ or soapenv//ser:GS//requestHeader//req:clientUsername/*

Comment: I will ask another question because another situation is occured